# Python: Extracting device and lens information from video metadata

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, metadata

I am interested in extracting device and lens information from videos.  Specifically, make and model of the device and the focal length.  I was able to do this successfully for still images using the `exifread` module and extract a whole bunch of very useful information:

```
image type      : MPO
Image ImageDescription: Shot with DxO ONE
Image Make: DxO
Image Model: DxO ONE
Image Orientation: Horizontal (normal)
Image XResolution: 300
Image YResolution: 300
Image ResolutionUnit: Pixels/Inch
Image Software: V3.0.0 (2b448a1aee) APP:1.0
Image DateTime: 2022:04:05 14:53:45
Image YCbCrCoefficients: [299/1000, 587/1000, 57/500]
Image YCbCrPositioning: Centered
Image ExifOffset: 158
Thumbnail Compression: JPEG (old-style)
Thumbnail XResolution: 300
Thumbnail YResolution: 300
Thumbnail ResolutionUnit: Pixels/Inch
Thumbnail JPEGInterchangeFormat: 7156
Thumbnail JPEGInterchangeFormatLength: 24886
EXIF ExposureTime: 1/3
EXIF FNumber: 8
EXIF ExposureProgram: Aperture Priority
EXIF ISOSpeedRatings: 100
EXIF SensitivityType: ISO Speed
EXIF ISOSpeed: 100
EXIF ExifVersion: 0221
EXIF DateTimeOriginal: 2022:04:05 14:53:45
EXIF DateTimeDigitized: 2022:04:05 14:53:45
EXIF ComponentsConfiguration: CrCbY
EXIF CompressedBitsPerPixel: 3249571/608175
EXIF ExposureBiasValue: 0
EXIF MaxApertureValue: 212/125
EXIF SubjectDistance: 39/125
EXIF MeteringMode: MultiSpot
EXIF LightSource: Unknown
EXIF Flash: Flash did not fire
EXIF FocalLength: 1187/100
EXIF SubjectArea: [2703, 1802, 675, 450]
EXIF MakerNote: [68, 88, 79, 32, 79, 78, 69, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0, ... ]
EXIF SubSecTime: 046
EXIF SubSecTimeOriginal: 046
EXIF SubSecTimeDigitized: 046
EXIF FlashPixVersion: 0100
EXIF ColorSpace: sRGB
EXIF ExifImageWidth: 5406
EXIF ExifImageLength: 3604
Interoperability InteroperabilityIndex: R98
Interoperability InteroperabilityVersion: [48, 49, 48, 48]
EXIF InteroperabilityOffset: 596
EXIF FileSource: Digital Camera
EXIF ExposureMode: Auto Exposure
EXIF WhiteBalance: Auto
EXIF DigitalZoomRatio: 1
EXIF FocalLengthIn35mmFilm: 32
EXIF SceneCaptureType: Standard
EXIF ImageUniqueID: C01A1709306530020220405185345046
EXIF BodySerialNumber: C01A1709306530
```

Unfortunately, I have been unable to extract this kind of info from videos so far.

This is what I have tried so far, with the `ffmpeg` module:

```
import ffmpeg
from pprint import pprint

test_video = "my_video.mp4"
pprint(ffmpeg.probe(test_video)["streams"])
```

And the output I get contains a lot of info but nothing related to the device or lens, which is what I am looking for:

```
[{'avg_frame_rate': '30/1',
  'bit_rate': '1736871',
  'bits_per_raw_sample': '8',
  'chroma_location': 'left',
  'codec_long_name': 'H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10',
  'codec_name': 'h264',
  'codec_tag': '0x31637661',
  'codec_tag_string': 'avc1',
  'codec_time_base': '1/60',
  'codec_type': 'video',
  'coded_height': 1088,
  'coded_width': 1920,
  'display_aspect_ratio': '16:9',
  'disposition': {'attached_pic': 0,
                  'clean_effects': 0,
                  'comment': 0,
                  'default': 1,
                  'dub': 0,
                  'forced': 0,
                  'hearing_impaired': 0,
                  'karaoke': 0,
                  'lyrics': 0,
                  'original': 0,
                  'timed_thumbnails': 0,
                  'visual_impaired': 0},
  'duration': '20.800000',
  'duration_ts': 624000,
  'has_b_frames': 0,
  'height': 1080,
  'index': 0,
  'is_avc': 'true',
  'level': 40,
  'nal_length_size': '4',
  'nb_frames': '624',
  'pix_fmt': 'yuv420p',
  'profile': 'Constrained Baseline',
  'r_frame_rate': '30/1',
  'refs': 1,
  'sample_aspect_ratio': '1:1',
  'start_pts': 0,
  'start_time': '0.000000',
  'tags': {'creation_time': '2021-05-08T13:23:20.000000Z',
           'encoder': 'AVC Coding',
           'handler_name': 'VideoHandler',
           'language': 'und'},
  'time_base': '1/30000',
  'width': 1920},
 {'avg_frame_rate': '0/0',
  'bit_rate': '79858',
  'bits_per_sample': 0,
  'channel_layout': 'stereo',
  'channels': 2,
  'codec_long_name': 'AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)',
  'codec_name': 'aac',
  'codec_tag': '0x6134706d',
  'codec_tag_string': 'mp4a',
  'codec_time_base': '1/48000',
  'codec_type': 'audio',
  'disposition': {'attached_pic': 0,
                  'clean_effects': 0,
                  'comment': 0,
                  'default': 1,
                  'dub': 0,
                  'forced': 0,
                  'hearing_impaired': 0,
                  'karaoke': 0,
                  'lyrics': 0,
                  'original': 0,
                  'timed_thumbnails': 0,
                  'visual_impaired': 0},
  'duration': '20.864000',
  'duration_ts': 1001472,
  'index': 1,
  'max_bit_rate': '128000',
  'nb_frames': '978',
  'profile': 'LC',
  'r_frame_rate': '0/0',
  'sample_fmt': 'fltp',
  'sample_rate': '48000',
  'start_pts': 0,
  'start_time': '0.000000',
  'tags': {'creation_time': '2021-05-08T13:23:20.000000Z',
           'handler_name': 'SoundHandler',
           'language': 'und'},
  'time_base': '1/48000'}]
```

Are these pieces of info available for videos? Should I be using a different package?

Thanks.

Edit:

`pprint(ffmpeg.probe(test_video)["format"])` gives

```
{'bit_rate': '1815244',
 'duration': '20.864000',
 'filename': 'my_video.mp4',
 'format_long_name': 'QuickTime / MOV',
 'format_name': 'mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2',
 'nb_programs': 0,
 'nb_streams': 2,
 'probe_score': 100,
 'size': '4734158',
 'start_time': '0.000000',
 'tags': {'artist': 'Microsoft Game DVR',
          'compatible_brands': 'mp41isom',
          'creation_time': '2021-05-08T12:12:33.000000Z',
          'major_brand': 'mp42',
          'minor_version': '0',
          'title': 'Snipping Tool'}}
```

Comment: I think EXIF data is stored at format level. Look in `format` for the side data, it should be under something like `side_data`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your suggestion, where should I be looking for `format` or `side_data`?

Comment: Don't know exactly what's in the output dict of `ffmpeg.probe(test_video)`, but I suspect there is an item with `'format'` key (or something similar. Look in it for the side data item

Comment: Edited post to include contents of `format`, still not seeing what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

OK, then it's elsewhere in the file... you can try the following to dig further:

```
pprint(ffmpeg.probe(test_video,show_data=None,private=None))
```

These are 2 other info that you can pull up using ffprobe. See [the doc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Main-options)

[update]

I played around with a JPEG file which has an EXIF info, and I was able to get the info via

```
ffprobe -show_entries frames -read_intervals %+#1 JPGFILE
```

which should translate to

```
pprint(ffmpeg.probe(test_video,show_frames=None,read_intervals='%+#1'))
```

Comment: I am getting the same output as before, a dictionary with two keys `format` and `streams`, with the same values as before.

Comment: With your update, I am getting the a new key called `frames` in the output, but still not seeing the info I need.

Btw, you tried on an image (jpeg) or a video?  My issue is with videos, I am getting this info from still images correctly.

Comment: yeah, jpeg. i don't have any video with exif data on my pc to try out...

Comment: Try remove `read_intervals='%+#1` and see what happens

Comment: Just gives me a whole bunch of frames

Comment: If you could post a short vid containing the data I'd be happy to look into it

Comment: I have tried using other software to read the metadata, and  also read the info on the camera app of the smartphones used to take the videos. I don't see any lens or sensor information for videos, although I see them for still images. I am pretty sure that this info is not carried over for videos for whatever reason.  

I will stop digging into this further, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a ton of information in a video file from a Canon R5 using exiftool.  https://exiftool.org/

I haven't figured out to extract this info with ffprobe yet.

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.62
File Name                       : MYA_8152.MP4
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 818 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2023:05:13 16:25:59-07:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2023:05:13 16:36:20-07:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2023:05:12 11:03:32-07:00
File Permissions                : -rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : MP4
File Type Extension             : mp4
MIME Type                       : video/mp4
Major Brand                     : MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]
Minor Version                   : 0.0.1
Compatible Brands               : mp42, avc1, CAEP
Compressor Version              : CanonMP4_002/10.00.00/00.00.02
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Co-sited
Exposure Time                   : 1/1600
F Number                        : 3.5
Exposure Program                : Manual
Sensitivity Type                : Recommended Exposure Index
Recommended Exposure Index      : 500
Exif Version                    : 0231
Date/Time Original              : 2023:04:16 09:18:11
Offset Time                     : -08:00
Offset Time Original            : -08:00
Offset Time Digitized           : -08:00
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Shutter Speed Value             : 1/1579
Aperture Value                  : 3.5
Flash                           : No Flash
Focal Length                    : 91.0 mm
Macro Mode                      : Normal
Self Timer                      : Off
Quality                         : Standard (RAW)
Canon Flash Mode                : n/a
Continuous Drive                : Movie
Focus Mode                      : Movie Servo AF
Record Mode                     : MP4
Canon Image Size                : Unknown (136)
Easy Mode                       : Manual
Digital Zoom                    : None
Contrast                        : Normal
Saturation                      : Normal
Metering Mode                   : Center-weighted average
Focus Range                     : Auto
Canon Exposure Mode             : Manual
Lens Type                       : Sigma 24-105mm f/4 DG OS HSM | A or Other Lens
Max Focal Length                : 200 mm
Min Focal Length                : 70 mm
Focal Units                     : 1/mm
Max Aperture                    : 2.8
Min Aperture                    : 32
Flash Activity                  : 0
Flash Bits                      : E-TTL
Focus Continuous                : Single
Image Stabilization             : Off (2)
Zoom Source Width               : 0
Zoom Target Width               : 0
Manual Flash Output             : n/a
Color Tone                      : Normal
Focal Type                      : Zoom
Auto ISO                        : 100
Base ISO                        : 4150
Measured EV                     : 13.63
Target Aperture                 : 3.6
Target Exposure Time            : 1/1625
Exposure Compensation           : 0
White Balance                   : Manual Temperature (Kelvin)
Slow Shutter                    : None
Shot Number In Continuous Burst : 0
Optical Zoom Code               : n/a
Camera Temperature              : 40 C
Flash Guide Number              : 0
Flash Exposure Compensation     : 0
Auto Exposure Bracketing        : Off
AEB Bracket Value               : 0
Control Mode                    : n/a
Measured EV 2                   : 33
Bulb Duration                   : 0
Camera Type                     : EOS High-end
Auto Rotate                     : Rotate 270 CW
ND Filter                       : Off
Canon Image Type                : MVI:Canon EOS R5
Canon Firmware Version          : Firmware Version 1.5.0
Canon Model ID                  : EOS R5
Thumbnail Image Valid Area      : 0 159 15 104
Image Unique ID                 : f653679015d24b54afd749cfa2cb9be1
Time Zone                       : -08:00
Time Zone City                  : Los Angeles
Daylight Savings                : Off
Battery Type                    : LP-E6
Bracket Mode                    : Off
Bracket Value                   : 0
Bracket Shot Number             : 0
Raw Jpg Size                    : Large
WB Bracket Mode                 : Off
WB Bracket Value AB             : 0
WB Bracket Value GM             : 0
Live View Shooting              : On
Focus Distance Upper            : inf
Focus Distance Lower            : 81.91 m
Shutter Mode                    : Mechanical
Flash Exposure Lock             : Off
RF Lens Type                    : n/a
Internal Serial Number          : FQ0260894
Exposure Level Increments       : 1/3 Stop
ISO Speed Increments            : 1/3 Stop
AEB Auto Cancel                 : On
AEB Sequence                    : 0,-,+
AEB Shot Count                  : 3 shots
Safety Shift                    : Disable
Usable Shooting Modes           : Flags 0x13f
Shutter Speed Range             : Manual: Hi 1/8123; Lo 31.9; Auto: Hi 1/4064; Lo 1/127
Aperture Range                  : Manual: Closed 64; Open 1; Auto: Closed 25; Open 2.6
Same Exposure For New Aperture  : Disable
AE Lock Meter Mode After Focus  : Evaluative
Dial Direction Tv Av            : Normal
Custom Controls                 : 29 0 19 0 0 65535 65535 65535 136 0 0 65535 65535 65535 29 0 4 0 53 0 25 0 7 0 13 0 14 2 91 2 29 0 29 0 29 0 29 0 29 0 29 0 29 0 0 0 0 0 90 0 29 0 54 0 78 0 88 0 103 0 39 0 105 0 65535 53 0 0 3 5376 3840 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5200 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 65535 0 7 3 4 31 1 4 0 0 0 1
Shutter Release Without Lens    : Enable
Control Ring Rotation           : Normal
Add Aspect Ratio Info           : Off
Default Erase Option            : Cancel selected
Retract Lens On Power Off       : Enable
Add IPTC Information            : Disable
Audio Compression               : Enable
Tone Curve                      : Standard
Sharpness                       : 4
Sharpness Frequency             : n/a
Sensor Red Level                : 0
Sensor Blue Level               : 0
White Balance Red               : 0
White Balance Blue              : 0
Color Temperature               : 5100
Picture Style                   : Standard
Digital Gain                    : 0
WB Shift AB                     : 0
WB Shift GM                     : 0
VRD Offset                      : 0
Sensor Width                    : 8352
Sensor Height                   : 5586
Sensor Left Border              : 144
Sensor Top Border               : 112
Sensor Right Border             : 8335
Sensor Bottom Border            : 5575
Black Mask Left Border          : 0
Black Mask Top Border           : 0
Black Mask Right Border         : 0
Black Mask Bottom Border        : 0
Picture Style User Def          : Standard; Standard; Standard
Picture Style PC                : None; None; None
Custom Picture Style File Name  :
Peripheral Illumination Corr    : Off
Auto Lighting Optimizer         : Off
Highlight Tone Priority         : Unknown (2)
Long Exposure Noise Reduction   : Off
High ISO Noise Reduction        : Standard
Digital Lens Optimizer          : Off
HDR                             : Off
HDR Effect                      : Natural
Compression Format              : Editing (ALL-I)
Canon Log Version               : OFF
User Comment                    :
Sub Sec Time                    : 58
Sub Sec Time Original           : 58
Sub Sec Time Digitized          : 58
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : sRGB
Exif Image Width                : 160
Exif Image Height               : 120
Interoperability Index          : THM - DCF thumbnail file
Interoperability Version        : 0100
Related Image Width             : 3840
Related Image Height            : 2160
Focal Plane X Resolution        : 240.5447498
Focal Plane Y Resolution        : 320.5438226
Focal Plane Resolution Unit     : inches
Custom Rendered                 : Normal
Exposure Mode                   : Manual
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Owner Name                      :
Serial Number                   : 212024001423
Lens Info                       : 70-200mm f/0
Lens Model                      : TAMRON SP 70-200mm F/2.8 Di VC USD A009
Lens Serial Number              : 0000000000
GPS Version ID                  : 2.3.0.0
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:2 (2 1)
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 26697 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Make                            : Canon
Camera Model Name               : Canon EOS R5
User Rating                     : 0
Movie Header Version            : 0
Create Date                     : 2023:04:16 17:18:11
Modify Date                     : 2023:04:16 17:18:11
Time Scale                      : 30000
Duration                        : 17.45 s
Preferred Rate                  : 1
Preferred Volume                : 100.00%
Preview Time                    : 0 s
Preview Duration                : 0 s
Poster Time                     : 0 s
Selection Time                  : 0 s
Selection Duration              : 0 s
Current Time                    : 0 s
Next Track ID                   : 3
Track Header Version            : 0
Track Create Date               : 2023:04:16 17:18:11
Track Modify Date               : 2023:04:16 17:18:11
Track ID                        : 1
Track Duration                  : 17.45 s
Track Layer                     : 0
Track Volume                    : 0.00%
Image Width                     : 3840
Image Height                    : 2160
Graphics Mode                   : srcCopy
Op Color                        : 0 0 0
Compressor ID                   : avc1
Source Image Width              : 3840
Source Image Height             : 2160
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Bit Depth                       : 24
Color Profiles                  : nclx
Color Primaries                 : BT.709
Transfer Characteristics        : BT.709
Matrix Coefficients             : BT.709
Video Frame Rate                : 29.97
Matrix Structure                : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
Media Header Version            : 0
Media Create Date               : 2023:04:16 17:18:11
Media Modify Date               : 2023:04:16 17:18:11
Media Time Scale                : 30000
Media Duration                  : 17.45 s
Media Language Code             : eng
Handler Type                    : Time Code
Other Format                    : tmcd
Playback Frame Rate             : 29.97002997
Media Data Size                 : 817652876
Media Data Offset               : 131088
Flash Exposure Compensation     : 0
Drive Mode                      : Continuous Shooting
Flash Type                      : Built-In Flash
ISO                             : 4150
Lens                            : 70.0 - 200.0 mm
Red Eye Reduction               : Off
Shooting Mode                   : Manual
Shutter Curtain Sync            : 1st-curtain sync
Aperture                        : 3.5
Image Size                      : 3840x2160
Lens ID                         : Tamron SP 70-200mm f/2.8 Di VC USD
Megapixels                      : 8.3
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 2.2
Shutter Speed                   : 1/1600
Create Date                     : 2023:04:16 09:18:11.58-08:00
Date/Time Original              : 2023:04:16 09:18:11.58-08:00
Modify Date                     : 2023:04:16 09:18:11.58-08:00
Avg Bitrate                     : 375 Mbps
Rotation                        : 270
Lens                            : 70.0 - 200.0 mm (35 mm equivalent: 156.2 - 446.3 mm)
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.013 mm
Depth Of Field                  : inf (119.02 m - inf)
Field Of View                   : 10.1 deg
Focal Length                    : 91.0 mm (35 mm equivalent: 203.1 mm)
Hyperfocal Distance             : 175.74 m
Light Value                     : 8.9
```